# How do I get a column in CSV in reverse order into php?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I would like to know how can I get a specific column (in my case the second column) from CSV in reverse order into PHP? For example if my file is

```
my, name, is, marwan
here, goes, thing, some
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Now the output the I want in php would be

```
my -      some -    1
name -    thing -   2
is -      goes -    3
marwan -  here -    4
```

My existing PHP code for printing everything in normal order is

```
for($num = 1; $num <= 1; $num++) {

        if(file_exists('1.csv')) {

          $csvData = file_get_contents('1.csv');
          $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
          $array = array();
          foreach ($lines as $line) { $array[] = str_getcsv($line); }

          // count number of columns and minus 1 from it
          $count =  count($array[0]) - 1;

          for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {

            $first_column = $array[0][$x];
            $second_column = $array[1][$x];
            $third_column = $array[2][$x];

           // Now just outputting the values...

          ";
          }

        }
      }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Put them in array and then use the array_reverse function

Comment: `$second_column = $array[1][$count - $x];`

Comment: @MariosNikolaou How do I do it exactly? What I tried to do is `$second_column = array_reverse($array[1][$x]);` but it tells me " Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array". Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @MarwanAnsari yes it's correct, the ''$array[1][$x]'' it's not array. Convert it to array and then add it in the function

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can do it easily:

```
<?php
// defining a test array similar to yours
$records = array(
    array(1, 'abc', '111'),
    array(2, 'def', '222'),
    array(3, 'ijk', '333'),
    array(4, 'lmn', '444'),
    array(5, 'opq', '555'),
); 

// getting the column and reversing it
$col1rev = array_reverse(array_column($records, 1));
?>
```

Comment: how about dealing with the specific question.

Comment: he needs to get a column in reversed order ... if i correctly understand the question, this code does exactly that.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, but anyway I tried to help

Comment: @Reflective I wanted to reverse it from the CSV file. However someone already have answered my query. Thanks alot for you answer too!

Comment: You have your values in $array, so just change $records to $array, just wanted to show more general case and use 1,2,3 ... etc for the column you want to reverse

Answer (score -1):

You need to first make the CSV in to an array then reverse the second line.

Once that is done you foreach the first item in the array and use the key to output the other values.

```
$arr = explode("\n", $csv);
Foreach($arr as $key => &$line){
    $line = explode(", ", $line);
    If($key == 1) $line = array_reverse($line);
}
Unset($line);

Foreach($arr[0] as $key => $val){
    Echo $val . "\t-\t" . $arr[1][$key] . "\t-\t" . $arr[2][$key] ."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
// The output here on SO looks odd but in reality it's tab separated
my  -   some    -   1
name    -   thing   -   2
is  -   goes    -   3
marwan  -   here    -   4
```

https://3v4l.org/MNLLF

Comment: I have solved the issue through a different method. Thanks alot for providing your method also!